Relation between the derivative and the covariant derivative?
In Do Carmo's "Differential geometry of curves and surfaces", he gives the covariant derivative for a differentiable field of unit vectors in the following way:

Let $w$ be a differentiable field of unit vectors along a parametrized curve $\alpha:I\rightarrow S$ on an oriented surface $S$. Since $w(t),t \in I$ is a unit vector field, $\frac{dw}{dt}(t)$ is normal to $w(t)$($0=1'=(w^2)'=2ww'$), and therefore
\begin{equation}
\frac{Dw}{dt}=\lambda(N\wedge w(t)).
\end{equation}
The value $\lambda$ is called the $\textbf{algebraic value of the covariant derivative}$ and is denoted by $[\frac{Dw}{dt}]$.

After this, he introduces the following Lemma:

Let $v$ and $w$ be two differentiable vector fields along he curve $\alpha:I\rightarrow S$, with $|w(t)|=|v(t)|=1, t \in I$(meaning they are unit vector fields). Then
\begin{equation}
[\frac{Dw}{dt}]-[\frac{Dv}{dt}]=\frac{d\phi}{dt},
\end{equation}
where $\phi$ is the angle from $v$ to $w$.

I have some problems with parts of the proof of this:

First, assume that $\phi \neq 0$. Since $\langle v,w \rangle = \cos \phi$ we obtain
\begin{equation}
\langle v', w \rangle +  \langle v, w' \rangle = -\sin\phi\phi',
\end{equation}
hence,
\begin{equation}
\langle \frac{Dv}{dt}, w \rangle + \langle v, \frac{Dw}{dt} \rangle = \sin\phi\phi'.
\end{equation}
But it holds that
\begin{equation}
\langle \frac{Dv}{dt}, w \rangle  + \langle \lambda N \wedge v, w \rangle = [\frac{Dv}{dt}]\langle N \wedge v, w \rangle.
\end{equation}
Thus, it follows that
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\langle \frac{Dv}{dt}, w \rangle + \langle v, \frac{Dw}{dt} \rangle&= [\frac{Dv}{dt}]\langle N \wedge v, w \rangle + [\frac{Dw}{dt}]\langle v, N \wedge w\rangle \\
&=([\frac{Dv}{dt}]-[\frac{Dw}{dt}])\sin\phi=\sin \phi \phi'.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

My first problem is with the second equation in the proof. I do not understand how he arrives at this equation with the above definition for the covariant derivative. Furthermore, I believe the missing '-' sign in front of sin is incorrect, because in Lee's 'Riemannian Manifolds', Lemma 5.2 he shows the following for the covariant derivative:

$\frac{d}{dt}\langle U(t), V(t) \rangle = \langle \frac{D}{dt}U(t),V(t)\rangle + \langle U(t), \frac{D}{dt} V(t)\rangle$.

I assume this sign cancels out in the last equation but I also cannot see how he arrives at it. Does it simply hold that

$\langle N \wedge v, w \rangle = \sin \phi$

If yes, why?
Thanks in advance. So far the other proofs from Do Carmo I have gone through were fairly detailed and well laid out, but this one does seem to skip a bunch of steps.

There's an unfortunate typo in this proof, besides the $-$ part that you mentioned, the equation
\begin{equation}
\langle \frac{Dv}{dt}, w \rangle  + \langle \lambda N \wedge v, w \rangle = [\frac{Dv}{dt}]\langle N \wedge v, w \rangle.
\end{equation}
should be
\begin{equation}
\langle \frac{Dv}{dt}, w \rangle \ {\color{red}=} \ \langle \lambda N \wedge v, w \rangle = [\frac{Dv}{dt}]\langle N \wedge v, w \rangle.
\end{equation}
On the other hand, note that for any linearly independent vector $\vec x_1, \vec x_2$ in $\mathbb R^3$,
$$ (\vec x_1, \vec x_2, \vec x_1\wedge \vec x_2)$$
forms a positive basis for $\mathbb R^3$. Hence
$$ (N, v, N\wedge v)$$
forms a positive basis for $\mathbb R^3$. Since $w$ is a unit vector and is orthogonal to $N$,
$$ w = \cos \varphi N + \sin \varphi (N\wedge v)\Rightarrow \langle N\wedge v, w\rangle = \sin\varphi.$$

Thank you, it is unfortunate how full of typos the book is. Often they don't affect readability but sometimes they change entire proofs and make them immensely harder to understand and follow.
